# Ajax Call on image button

Tags: 7

I want to use ajax call on image button

here is my code.

```
function clicktell_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if($form_id=='user_profile_form') {

       $form['linkb'] = array(
            '#type' => 'image_button',
            '#href' => '',
            '#title' => t('something'),

            '#name' => 'linkb',
            '#ajax' => array(
                'method' => 'html', // this is important without this if else condition for ajax will not work.
                'effect' => 'fade',
                'callback' => 'clicktell_verification',
                'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',),
        );
        $form['cardnresp'] = array(
            '#type' => 'hidden',
            //'#default_value' => '',
            '#title' => t('This is where msg comes'),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_textfield_div">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
        $form['#validate'][]='clicktell_error';  


    }
    return $form;
}
```

and

```
function clicktell_error($form, &$form_state) {
  //my code 
}

function clicktell_verification($form, &$form_state) {
 //my code
}
```

But now when i click on image button it jst refresh the page and no ajax call happnes

Does anybody have idea regarding this

Thanks

Comment: Might help if you could (on a copy of course) trim your code in omitted functions to minimum amount needed to show your problem. If it works with functions empty, add that note in comments inside these functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
function clicktell_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if($form_id=='user_profile_form') {

       $form['linkb'] = array(
            '#type' => 'image_button',
            '#href' => '',
            '#title' => t('something'),

            '#name' => 'linkb',
            '#ajax' => array(
                'method' => 'html', // this is important without this if else condition for ajax will not work.
                'effect' => 'fade',
                 'prevent' => 'mousedown',
                'callback' => 'clicktell_verification',
                'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',),
        );
        $form['cardnresp'] = array(
            '#type' => 'hidden',
            //'#default_value' => '',
            '#title' => t('This is where msg comes'),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_textfield_div">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
        $form['#validate'][]='clicktell_error';  


    }
    return $form;
}
```

This will run ajax but you may feel form is submitting but there is no actual submitting of form

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set [`#ajax_prevent`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_prevent). It should default to 'click' all right, but my experience says sometimes it does not, and sometimes it is not sufficient. Try to add this to your ajax settings:

```
'prevent' => 'submit click mousedown',
```

Comment: not working. Still form submits